$e$ number and perfect roots
I was looking for efficient expressions of the number $e$ and wondered about this:
$$
\forall x, y \in \mathbb{N}, \ (x, y) \neq (1, 3) \implies \left\lfloor 10^x \cdot e \right\rfloor^{1/y} \notin \mathbb{N}
$$
Basically, there are no natural numbers $x$ and $y$ (except for $x = 1$ and $y = 3$) such that multiplying $e$ by a power of $10$ raised to $x$ will result in a number whose integer part is a perfect root.
Is this statement true or false? Why?
EDIT
Ok, so because of the comments here, I got interested in this process of finding perfect roots for the truncated integer parts of multiple powers of 10 of different numbers.
I checked a couple thousand numbers by generating two samples:
The first sample (the rational sample) came from dividing two random integer numbers between 1 and 1e5, adding them to the sample if they weren't already present.
The second sample (the irrational sample) was generated by getting random numbers from 1 to 1e5 that were not perfect squares, then adding their square roots to the sample if they weren't already present.
The samples were sized around 30k and 60k respectively.
For each number in each sample, I checked the proportion of perfect roots in the decimal part (out of the first 15 digits) by progressively multiplying by 10 and getting the integer part, then checking if that was a perfect root up to a degree of around 40. Any match counts as one, so if a perfect root is found, it stops for that decimal place and proceeds to the next.
This gave me two perfect root proportion samples that had different qualities. Using value_counts() from pandas, the samples had these characteristics:
   Rational Sample
---------------------
Proportion Percentage

0.000000    0.391436
0.066667    0.422468
0.133333    0.155701
0.200000    0.026667
0.266667    0.003218
0.333333    0.000287
0.400000    0.000159
0.533333    0.000032
0.866667    0.000032


  Irrational Sample
---------------------
Proportion Percentage

0.000000    0.895979
0.066667    0.099981
0.133333    0.003770
0.200000    0.000253
0.266667    0.000016

Basically, out of the rational sample, most numbers (60.8%) had at least one perfect root in its decimal part.
Meanwhile, for the irrational numbers very few if any (10.4%) had any perfect root in their decimal part.
I did a chi squared test and it was significant ($\chi^2 = 2.697e4$).
I had an intuition I would get a result like this, is this difference significant or just coincidental? What does it mean?
EDIT 2
This requires further analysis, because I used a cutoff to calculate the perfect roots that was skewing the results.
Also this should be tried with different types of irrational numbers, not just imperfect square roots.
I changed the cutoff and I'm getting different results, I will try to make it more precise.

Not enough is known about the decimal expansion of $e$ to prove you never get a perfect power. How far have you tested values of $x$? Anyway, there's no reason to think there's anything special about $e$. You could ask the same kind of question about $\pi$, or $\sqrt2$.

Just around 15 digits, I haven't properly tested it, but I wondered if someone could confirm or disprove. I havent checked other irrational numbers, let me see.

Yes I get similar results for other irrationals.

I just tested upto x=60 in Sage. It doesn't look promising...

So, this is true but is just a probabilistic statement? It could have been true or false but there is no other way of proving definetly that it should have been necesarily true rather than checking manually? but even then it seems unintuitive.

Perhaps I haven't made myself clear. 1) I can't prove anything here; I'm just giving my opinions. 2) In my opinion, the only way to prove that there are more examples of perfect powers is to find some by computing. $e$ is known to many, many decimal places, and it's not too hard to determine whether a number with thousands of digits is a perfect power. 3) In my opinion, mathematics does not yet have the tools to prove that there are no more perfect powers.
